# override list<T>.ToString()

Tags: c#

ok, im in learning stage already, make search and dont find, i want return .ToString() from my list<> but this in using

```
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Text;

namespace eciv {
    using Pontos = List<Ponto>;  // I need override ToString()

    public partial class FPrincipal : Form  {

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
            Pontos aa = new Pontos();
            aa.Add(new Ponto(2, 3));
            aa.Add(new Ponto(3, 4));
            textBox1.Text = aa.ToString();  // here I need help  
        }
    }

    public class Ponto {

        public double X;
        public double Y;

        public Ponto() {}

        public Ponto(double x, double y) { 
            this.X = x; this.Y = y; 
        }

        public Ponto(Ponto p) { 
            this.X = p.X; 
            this.Y = p.Y; 
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            string s = "(" + this.X.ToString() + "," + this.Y.ToString() + ")";
            return s;
        }
    }   
}
```

In textBox I get this value

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[eciv.Ponto]
```

I want something like this

```
((2,3),(3,4))
```

I think it's this but it doesn't work

```
public override string ToString() : Pontos {  
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.Append("(");

    foreach (Ponto p in this) 
    {  
        s.Append(p.ToString() + ",");
    }

    s.Replace(",", ")", s.Length - 1, 1);
    return s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: `public override string ToString() : Pontos` is not c# syntax

Comment: so as i write i think some like these, im beginer

Comment: i need override Pontos (Pontos are list<T>) declared in line 4 with using

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot override a method in some class if you are not inheriting from that class. So the solution is simple - instead of creating name alias, create a class which inherits `List<Ponto>`:

```
public class Pontos : List<Ponto>
{
    public override string ToString() => $"({String.Join(",", this)})";
}
```

Or format list in place:

```
textBox1.Text = $"({String.Join(",", aa)})"; // consider use meaningful names for variables
```

I would go for the second option if you want to convert pontos list to string only once - string formatting is not a good reason to introduce a new type.

---

If you need to convert this list to string several times, you can create some private or extension method for formatting list of objects (not necessary Ponto objects). E.g.

```
public static string Stringify<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values)
   => $"({String.Join(",", values})";
```

And usage

```
textBox1.Text = aa.Stringify(); // works with List<int> etc
```

Links:

- [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) - don't use StringBuilder if you want to join items in one string
- [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) - extend existing classes with new functionality
- [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#string-interpolation) - nice new syntax for formatting strings

Comment: i use this but first i need comment my `using Pontos = List<Ponto>;` to have `class Pontos`, become more fast, i have bigs polygons

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own `List<T>`, which overrides the `ToString()`-method

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.Append("(");
        foreach (var element in this)
        {
            s.Append(element.ToString() + ",");
        }
        s.Replace(",", ")", s.Length - 1, 1);
        return s.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `ToString()` on `List<T>`, you can create a string based on `ToString()` implementation you create for `Ponto` class like this:

```
Pontos aa = new Pontos();
aa.Add(new Ponto(2, 3));
aa.Add(new Ponto(3, 4));

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
s.Append("(");
s.Append(String.Join(",", aa));
s.Append(")");

textBox1.Text = s.ToString();
```